# Why can't we use DISTINCT keyword when we use ROLLUP operator?

Tags: sql-server

I am confused why can't we use DISTINCT keyword when we use ROLLUP operator? Is there a reason or it just the specification?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the query you are looking at.

Answer (score 1):

"select distinct" is useless and redundant if a query involves a GROUP BY clause.

By its nature a GROUP BY clause must produce uniquely defined rows, so as the rows are already unique "select distinct" adds no value whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a reasonable question at first glance.  But, usually one doesn't use `select distinct` with an aggregation query.  So, there really isn't a reason to support `rollup` with `select distinct`, because the former is used only with `group by` and the latter almost never.